# Remove items from Opera's Spatial Navigation flow?

Tags: html, opera, frontend, web-frontend

I've come a bit stuck this afternoon with a bug in my web application in the latest version of Opera.

Usually, it is possible to remove elements from the markup's tab-index flow by giving it the attribute:

```
tabindex="-1"
```

This means that when someone comes to the page and starts hitting their 'tab' key they will traverse the anchors/inputs in the document but those elements with -1 assigned will be ignored.

However, Opera's spatial navigation flow still allows users to access those elements via their keyboard.

Does anybody know of an alternate way of removing elements from Opera's spatial navigation flow in the same way that elements can in other browsers using tab-key document traversal?

Specifically: removing anchors from being accessible via Opera rather than inputs.

The markup below gives a rudimentary example. In non-Opera browsers you can use the tab key to go through the list, but it skips links 3, 4, and 7 because they have tabindex = -1 set.  In Opera using spatial navigation (Ctrl+down/up arrow) it will still focus on those links..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            :focus{border: 1px dashed green}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Link 3 (tabindex -1)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Link 4 (tabindex -1)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Link 7 (tabindex -1)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you ever hamper keyboard navigation?

Comment: MetalFrog: to give you a bit of an insight, this forms part of a carousel, so the intention is that via the keyboard the user should only be able to access the central content, whereas the panels either side are half on/half off the screen and partially faded out - disabled if you will - and thus shouldn't be accessible via keyboard unless brought into view (which is 100% possible via the kayboard by the way!)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Makes sense that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a nice way to do this. It's possible to do an ugly hack like `<a onfocus="document.moveFocusDown()" tabindex="-1">` but I would not recommend it because there isn't a good way to figure out if the user wants to go up or down..well, you could listen for keyup and do it from there if a tabindex=-1 element is focused and the key is arrow up/down, I guess..

I recommend you report a bug saying that spatnav should respect tabindex="-1" - IMO your code as-is is fine and it would make sense to change this on Opera's side. I'm happy to kick the bug in the general direction of the right developers once you've reported it. (I work on testing and QA at Opera).

Comment: Thanks hallvors, this is a pretty big website (9+ million visitors a week), so it's probably best that I avoid hack-type dependencies.

I've submitted a bug with Opera, reference is DSK-360057 - I've also linked it back to this discussion and attached the same HTML as shown at the top of this page.

Reassuring to find a bug that isn't my fault for once!!

Comment: Thank you, I will bring it to the attention of the right people and keep an eye on it myself. I can't promise a quick fix - spatnav is a much more complicated feature than you might think..

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, Opera has a [different type of keyboard navigation](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.51/en/keyboard.html) than most browsers. This actually makes it incredibly easy to navigate using keyboard navigation.

Now, back to your question... it works for me in Opera 10.61 1250 (Windows 7).  The following is my sample page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="textbox">
<input type="textbox" style="display:none">
<input type="textbox" tabindex="-1">
<input type="textbox">
</body>
</html>
```

The 2nd and 3rd inputs are skipped when I hit tab.

If this differs from what you have, please post a code sample.

Comment: Hi Hexxagonal, thanks for your comment.  Appologies: I wasn't clear enough in my question.  I'm actually referring to the traversal of anchors rather than form inputs.

In Opera you can use the tab key to traverse form inputs _only_, whilst using Opera's spatial navigation (Ctrl+down/up arrow) will traverse inputs and anchors (as the tab key does in other browsers; Forefix/Chrome, etc).

Comment: Ahh, ic. I assumed inputs when you said tab to the elements.  Would it be possible to move the image displayed in the carousel out of the anchor tag and set display:none on the anchor that's in the partially hidden carousel?

Comment: Also, are the users entirely upset about being able to select the partially hidden ones or is it more of a style thing? Even though, I'm a huge Opera fan and use it as my primary browser... it seems like a lot of work to support Opera.

Comment: He's aiming for perfection. I wish more webdevs were like him :-)

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this issue was to cache the href attribute as data- for each link that should not be included in the focus loop, then when the link can receive focus again, I restore the href from the cached data-.

http://jsfiddle.net/majornista/5pbFz/46/